# Spyder error on variable explorer

Tags: command-line, anaconda, spyder

I just installed `Anaconda 4.5.8` and Spyder via both `conda install spyder` and `sudo apt-get install spyder3`.

I run Spyder via `spyder` using terminal and the variable explorer works perfectly. But when I run via Spyder3 at Application Menu, I got this error:

```
Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console.
The error mesage was: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'numpy'",)
```

I use a simple one like `a = np.arange(0, 10, 1)`. It also fails on pandas DataFrame object.

It seems the system runs different Spyder from terminal and from Application menu. How do I fix this? I think it's too slow if I need to run it via terminal. I want the same Spyder just like the terminal's but launch it via Application Menu instead.

PS:
I change the Spyder's Application Menu Python Interpreter to Anaconda's folder `/home/hermonjay/anaconda3/bin/python3.6` and still got an error on the variable explorer.

Spyder's Anaconda version is `3.2.8` and Application is `3.2.6`.